# How to Insert (Append) Table into richTextBox Control

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I am trying to generate a function to enable users to insert table into a richTextBox winForm control.What I have is a Insert button which is fireing  an InsertForm winForm.The form contains two textboxes as txtRow and txtCol and a btnInsert.
Now, I would like to know is there any way which I append the table in the position of cursor?
Can you please help me to figure this up?
Thanks for your time in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use RTF to allow tables. According to [SelectedRtf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectedrtf.aspx) documentation, if nothing is selected then the RTF string is inserted at the current point.

```
myRichTextBox.SelectedRtf = RTFtablestring;
```

Comment: hi keyboardP,thanks for ur comment but can you plese let me know how I can do the first part of question,first? I google for using RTF in C# but I did'nt fine anything useful!. once again thanks for your time

Comment: You could create code that will generate RTF data for you as explained here:http://www.devx.com/asp/Article/17964/0/page/3